# no matlab executable were found

Tags: matlab, installation, ubuntu-12.10

I tried to install the "MATLAB - Scientific computing environment" from the software center but failed, because I got the error message "No MATLAB executables were found in the directories you specified. This package requires at least one local installation of MATLAB." My linux version is ubuntu 12.10. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
# Replace R2012a by your version:
sudo ln -s /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/matlab matlab
```

Otherwise you can also try `sudo apt-get install matlab-support`, which is basically an assistant for configuring MATLAB.

Now the command `matlab` should launch MATLAB.